# How to update links in html file stored in Firebase storage with the proper download URLs?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have multiple HTML files stored in Firebase storage. Those files contain regular HTML, and they include links to other files (css, js, etc) stored within Firebase storage as well.

In order to download a file in Firebase storage you usually have to get a proper download URL in your client, something like:

```
const ref = firebase.storage().ref('static/styles.css');
ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadUrl => ...download file here...)
```

Now, my HMTL file is rendered within an iframe. I can process this HTML file and replace all references to other css and js files in the client (Angular) with proper Firebase URLs, and the iframe renders the page just fine.

My issue occurs when one of the files downloaded by the iframe (usually css or js) references a third file. As this reference does not have the right Firebase URL, it fails.

For example, a css file referencing an image background:

```
background: #2a2f27 url(../images/banner.jpg) no-repeat;
```

The code above will fail.

Is there a way to serve those files with the Firebase URLs already in place? Maybe with a cloud function?

Another option could be to intercept those outgoing calls in the iframe itself and replace them before the calls are made, but I am afraid this is not possible for security reasons.

Comment: For those referenced files `../images/banner.jpg`, have you tried making them public and then instead of using relative path, specify the full path with Cloud Storage? With fine-grained access you can only make public some files of your bucket. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#choose_between_uniform_and_fine-grained_access

Comment: Is that supported? Is it documented somewhere in Firebase docs? @AntonioRamirez

Comment: Yes, it is. First I need to mention that a firebase project is also a Google Cloud Platform project. If you log in with your firebase email and password to [1], specify your firebase project id and go to Cloud Storage you will see the same buckets you have in firebase. From there you can click on the bucket and see if the access is uniform or fine-grained and make public.[2] 

[1] https://console.cloud.google.com/
[2] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#console